# Python: How to vectorize pandas columns as function parameters?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I want to use the function **calc_tfidf()** with Pandas vectorization. In the way is written below, **calc_tfidf()** receive pandas Series as parameters instead of the single value from the row.

```
db_df = pd.DataFrame()
db_df['username'] = ["a", "b", "c"]
db_df['num_followers'] = [10, 50, 100]
db_df['tweet_id'] = ["a1", "b1", 'c1']
db_df['hashtag'] = ["#h1", '#h2', 'h3']
db_df['sentiment_compound'] = [5, 3, 4]
db_df['total_users'] = 3

df_definitive['tfidf'] = calc_tfidf(df_definitive['username'], df_definitive['hashtag'], df_definitive['total_users'])
df_definitive['p'] = df_definitive['tfidf'] * df_definitive['num_followers'] * df_definitive['sentiment_compound']
```

I need a way to use pandas vectorize as function parameters, but I don't know how to do that.

Regards

Comment: Give a data sample of db_conn

Comment: db_conn is the name for my database API. **db_conn.get_number_users()** return the number of total users, it can be a single number. **db_conn.dump_all_db()** return a record with all the content in database.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the function `calc_tfidf()`. So I made up a dummy function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


db_df = pd.DataFrame()
db_df['username'] = ["a", "b", "c"]
db_df['num_followers'] = [10, 50, 100]
db_df['tweet_id'] = ["a1", "b1", 'c1']
db_df['hashtag'] = ["#h1", '#h2', 'h3']
db_df['sentiment_compound'] = [5, 3, 4]
db_df['total_users'] = 3

def tf_idf(username, hashtag, total_users):
    """This is some dummy tf_idf function that takes on three arguments
    and return some numerical value.  You haven't told us what tf_idf
    function looks like. So We made one up. Use your actual function
    here.

    """
    return len(username) + len(hashtag) + total_users

def p(x, y, z):
    return x * y * z


# use the numpy function vectorizer. (perhaps this is what you meant)
tf_idf  = np.vectorize(tf_idf)(db_df['username'],
                               db_df['hashtag'],
                               db_df['total_users'])

_p = np.vectorize(p)(db_df['tf_idf'],
                     db_df['num_followers'],
                     db_df['sentiment_compound'])


db_df['tf_idf'] = pd.Series(tf_idf)
db_df['p'] = pd.Series(_p)

print(db_df)
```